# Fetching html form values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

The following javascript code is for a "ping-pong" game I was asked to make:

```
var final_number = document.getElementById("input").value;
var current_number = 0;

var interval = setInterval(document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = ++current_number;
    if (current_number % 3 === 0){
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "ping";
    }
    if (current_number % 5 === 0){
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "pong";
    }   
    if (current_number % 15 === 0){
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "ping";
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "pong";
    }    
    if (current_number >= final_number){
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = 'Game Over';
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

It counts up from 0 to the number inputted in the form "input" in the html then says 'Game Over' when it reaches the number. The problem, however, is that it immediately says 'Game Over' without counting at all. I think the problem is with fetching the form value. It worked until iI introduced the variable "final_number" and put it in the last if statement (I used the number 50 before). Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You could use a debugger to actually see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parseInt when getting the value, otherwise it will be a string

```
var final_number = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value,10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a number with a Text so its comparing ASCII values ,
I think that you need to convert your value first